# How to recognise changes in specific property of object in state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I only want to run a hook when a property in an array of objects in state changes.

So for example only when the property "value" in one of the objects changes, I want to run a hook to send all the values to a server.

```
  const [steps, setSteps] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      value: "value 123", // If this changes
      disabled: false,
      active: true,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      value: "value 345", // If this changes
      disabled: false,
      active: true,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      value: "value 678", // If this changes
      disabled: false,
      active: true,
    },
  ]);
```

I don't want to send the values to a server if for example properties like "disabled" or "active" are changing.

To achieve this, I store the configuration (object of values) in a separate state variable and track the changes as follows. It works, but I don't know whether this is the right solution.

```
  const [configuration, setConfiguration] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    let updatedConfig = {};
    steps.forEach((step) => {
      if (step.value && step.active) {
        updatedConfig[step.id] = step.value;
      }
    });
    setConfiguration((prevConfig) => {
      // Check if new configuration has changed from previous and update state accordingly
      const changed =
        JSON.stringify(prevConfig) != JSON.stringify(updatedConfig);
      return changed ? updatedConfig : prevConfig;
    });
  }, [steps]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(configuration, "Send values to server!");
  },[configuration]);
```

Comment: Using JSON.stringify to compare objects isn't a good idea, generally (use the isEqual function from the lodash package instead, for example). Another attempt would be, to each property as an array in a separate state. Then you can track changes in this array. Another easy way is to use the configuration state as "server state" (so you store the steps every time you need to update them) and you update the server state whenever a "value" property of the step and configuration states mismatch.

Comment: Okay I will check lodash, but I can use JSON.stringify in this particular way because I know the order will be always the same. Properties in different states I had before, but for some reasons, I need this workaround now (too deep to explain).